# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute (method)

Tags: python, methods

I'm trying to write a chess game, and getting the above error when trying to move my Pawn. My first call of `my_board[0][0].passive_move()`works fine and correctly moves the object into the second list. But if I call it again immediately I get the error in the title, rather than moving the object into the third list.

```
__author__ = 'admin'

class Pawn:
    def __init__(self, y, x):
        self.board = my_board
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self):
        return "Pawn"

    def passive_move(self):
        self.board[self.y+1][self.x] = self
        self.board[self.y][self.x] = chr(self.y+65)+str(self.x+1)
        self.y += 1

class ChessBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = self.create_board

    def create_board(self):
        game_board = []
        letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
        for x in range(len(letters)):
            game_board.append([])
            for y in range(1, 9):
                game_board[x].append(str(letters[x])+str(y))

        return game_board

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_board = ChessBoard().create_board()

    for x in range(len(my_board)):
        my_board[0][x] = Pawn(0, x)


    my_board[0][0].passive_move()
    my_board[0][0].passive_move()


    print(my_board)
```

Comment: You do understand what the second line in `Pawn.passive_move()` does, right?

Comment: Doesn't it replace the previous position of the object with the original coordinate? At least that was my intention.

Comment: ... No, it injects a string into the list.

Comment: Why you are casting y as string?         self.board[self.y][self.x] = chr(self.y+65)+str(self.x+1)

Comment: Can you explain why that's an issue? I'm using strings as placeholders for each position in the list, so if a piece moves out of game_board[0][0], that position returns to the original A1 string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're calling `passive_move` twice on the same board coordinates:

```
my_board[0][0].passive_move()
my_board[0][0].passive_move()
```

After the first call, the pawn that was initially on that square will have moved up one, and so the square will hold a string rather than a `Pawn` instance. Since strings don't have a `passive_move` method, you get an error from the second call.

Note that if you only indexed `board` once and saved a reference to the `Pawn` instance you get, you could tell it to move twice. Try something like this:

```
pawn = my_board[0][0]
pawn.passive_move()
pawn.passive_move()
```